# How would you upload an image URL to an external website which generates a new URL for it and retrieve the newly generated url in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, upload, gif

I am creating a website which allows users to post links to gif images stored externally. Unfortunately gifs are terribly expensive and luckily I have found the following website which compresses them quite radically: http://gfycat.com/

Currently my app stores the url to the linked image (as of yet it is uncompressed and without the use of gfycat)

What I would like to do is to take the url that the user posts, use it to compress the gif via gfycat.com and then store the newly generated url (pointing to the compressed image) in my database.

How would I do this?

Sorry for the long explanation btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just took a look at gfycat.com, seems like they do have an accessible webservice at `http://gfycat.com/fetch/:url`

If this is the case, and you already have the URL you can very easily grab the 'minified' version of the gif by grabbing the URL and saving the file.

So, I would probably do something like this:

- Install `carrierwave` or another image upload gem of your choice

In the case you used the above gem...

assuming `Cat` is your model, and you have an uploader attached to it named `gif_photo`, and also assuming the original 'gif' url is stored as `original_gif_url`

You can do something like the following (assuming `@cat` is some instance of the cat model):

```
@cat.update_attribute(:remote_gif_photo_url, "http://gfycat.com/fetch/#{@cat.original_gif_url}")
```

as simple as that :)... to get back at the gif, you can simply call `@cat.gif_photo_url`

(again, assumptions for code above are using `carrierwave` syntax, but can easily be done with any of its alternatives.)

Comment: just realized, that given the situation you don't even really need HTTParty I don't think, you can probably just feed the URL directly, I'll update answer